# Spliting the address of US using regex PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I want to split the address into city, state, and zip code.

With my current regex pattern now, I can get the zip code and state already but I am having trouble matching the city.

Here is my current pattern

```
/\s*([^,]+?)\s*((?:\w{2,3}|(AVE))[A-Z]+?(?:\s[A-Z]+)?)\s*(\w{2})\s*(\d{5}(?:-\d{4})|\d{5}(?:-\s\d{4})?)/
```

Demo : https://regex101.com/r/kQ2dE7/1

With my demo above, I was able to match the city correctly but this is not applicable with other kinds of addresses.

https://regex101.com/r/kQ2dE7/2

https://regex101.com/r/kQ2dE7/4

I want the first capturing group to match only until a word that has numbers or a word with numbers only or words like ST, CT, AVE, DR.

For example:

> 11111 A BAY RD AAA111 SUNNY ISLES BEACH FL 33160-4266
>
> 11111 A BAY RD AAA111
>
> SUNNY ISLES BEACH
>
> FL
>
> 33160-4266

The first matching group should check if it contains a "ST" / "CT" / "DR" / "AVE" or word with number. Then it will match until that word.

Also if there are two instances of that word in a string, then it should match until the farthest word.

Example:

> 111 11TH ST AAAA2 BROOKLYN NY 11209- 4940
>
> 111 11TH ST AAAA2
>
> BROOKLYN
>
> NY
>
> 11209- 4940

(with this example, ST and a word with number is present, then it should match until the word with number.)

That's why I am trying to create a conditional statement to match certain words in my regex pattern. How to implement this in regex?

Comment: This is a fool's errand, especially if you are accepting user input. If you can state your required regex more clearly, probably someone can come up with one, but it will never work reliably. There are too many permutations.

Answer (score 0):

- The alternative `AVE` is useless in the group `(?:\w{2,3}|(AVE))`, since `AVE` is already matched by `\w{2,3}`.
- The group `(?:\w{2,3}|(AVE))` is useless in the 2nd capturing group - it just matches the city's 2 or 3 first characters; but the city name should start at a word boundary, so let's replace this group with just `\b`.
- Space-separated trailing parts of the city name may appear more than once (as in `SUNNY ISLES BEACH`, so the group `(?:\s[A-Z]+)` must have the quantifier `*` rather than `?`.
- `(\d{5}(?:-\d{4})|\d{5}(?:-\s\d{4})?)` can be simplified to `(\d{5}(?:-\s?\d{4})?)`.
- > The first matching group should check if it contains a "ST" / "CT" /
  >   "DR" / "AVE" or word with number. Then it will match until that word.
  >
  > Also if there are two instances of that word in a string, then it
  >   should match until the farthest word.

  I take it that you mean *two* or more *instances*. The 1st capturing group `([^,]+\b(?:ST|CT|DR|AVE|\w*\d\w*)\b)` would satisfy these requirements.

All changes above are incorporated into your regex here: https://regex101.com/r/uY7oM1/4

```
\s*([^,]+\b(?:ST|CT|DR|AVE|\w*\d\w*)\b)\s*(\b[A-Z]+?(?:\s[A-Z]+)*)\s*(\w{2})\s*(\d{5}(?:-\s?\d{4})?)
```